# Fan control problem in MSI GF75 Thin 9SC

Tags: settings, fan, system-settings, fancontrol, msi

I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04LTS. But in my laptop, fan doesn't work.In Windows OS, I use MSI DRAGON CENTER for controlling fan. But in Ubuntu, I can't find apps or solution to control my fan.

Comment: look at lmsensors for temp & fan ctrl